How to train GCN with batched data?
I have this code for defining GraphConvolution
class GraphConvolution(Module):
    """
    Simple GCN layer, similar to https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.02907
    """

    def __init__(self, in_features, out_features,bias=True):
        super(GraphConvolution, self).__init__()
        self.in_features = in_features
        self.out_features = out_features
        self.weight = Parameter(torch.FloatTensor(in_features, out_features))

        if bias:
            self.bias = Parameter(torch.FloatTensor(out_features))
        else:
            self.register_parameter('bias', None)
        self.reset_parameters()

    def reset_parameters(self):
        stdv = 1. / math.sqrt(self.weight.size(1))
        self.weight.data.uniform_(-stdv, stdv)
        if self.bias is not None:
            self.bias.data.uniform_(-stdv, stdv)

    def forward(self, input, adj):
        input = torch.squeeze(input)
        print("Input input shape:", input.shape)
        adj = torch.squeeze(adj)
        print('adj shape:'adj.shape)
        support = torch.mm(input, self.weight)
        output = torch.spmm(adj, support)
        if self.bias is not None:
            return output + self.bias
        else:
            return output

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__ + ' (' \
               + str(self.in_features) + ' -> ' \
               + str(self.out_features) + ')'

and I have this model:

class model(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, example, num_classes=10):
        super(DeepEZ, self).__init__()
        self.gc1 = GraphConvolution(246,120)
        self.gc2 = GraphConvolution(120,50)
        self.fc_class = torch.nn.Linear(50,2,bias=False)
        self.fc1 = torch.nn.Linear(246,60)
        self.fc2 = torch.nn.Linear(60,1)


    def forward(self, x, adj):
        out = F.leaky_relu(self.gc1(x, adj),negative_slope=0.1)
        out = F.leaky_relu(self.gc2(out, adj), negative_slope=0.1)
        out = F.leaky_relu(self.fc_class(out), negative_slope=0.1)
        ann_out = F.leaky_relu(self.fc1(out.view(out.size(1),out.size(0))),negative_slope=0.1)
        ann_out = F.leaky_relu(self.fc2(ann_out),negative_slope=0.1)

        out = torch.add(out,ann_out.view(ann_out.size(1),ann_out.size(0)))
        return out, ann_out
....

i want to train my model on batched data, meaning that X will be (batchsize, 246, 246) and the same for adj but I get this error
RuntimeError: self must be a matrix
on this line
support = torch.mm(input, self.weight)
can someone help how to modify the model to receive batched data?
